# integer solutions to bivariate polynomial of second degree

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I am trying to determine if there is a way to quickly determine if an equation of the following type $$0 = axy+x-y-A$$ has integer solutions ($a,A$ are integers).  If anyone knows how to do this or can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $a\ne 0$. The equation can be rewritten as $a^2xy+ax-ay-aA=0$. and then as 
$$(ax-1)(ay+1)=aA-1.$$
For given $a$ and $A$, we can look for solutions to $st=aA-1$. They must satisfy additional congruential conditions modulo $a$. But even without the congruential conditions, unless $aA=1$ we only have a finite number of candidates to examine: just let $s$ run over all divisors, positive and negative, of $aA-1$.  (And if $aA=1$, the problem is very easy.)

Comment: Dear Andre, Thank you so much for your answer! I am going to try this now!

Comment: You are welcome. I could not write much more, since the rest may depend on number-theoretic properties of $a$ and $A$, so details may change as $a$ and $A$ vary. With $a$ and $A$ explicitly identified, one could give a complete description.

Comment: Thanks again Andre! I just looked into this and I think I need more  clarification. Could you please give me an example of congruential conditions and how they will factor into the solution, let's say for a = 6 and A any odd number. I would like to know if there is a way to derive an easy test to check if integer solutions exist, determining them may be secondary

Comment: So let $A=11$. We look for solutions of $(6x-1)(6y+1)=65$. There is always the trivial solutions from taking $x=0$ or $y=0$. In our case we also get non-trivial solutions by taking $6x-1=5$ or $6x-1=-13$. Now take $A=15$. Then $aA-1=89$, prime, so there are only the trivial solutions.

Comment: great! thank you for your help!

Comment: I chose the two values of $A$ to illustrate the fact that **number-theoretic** properties of $aA-1$ can become relevant.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much again for your help! I really appreciate it!